# What am I missing in Microsoft's contravariance example?

Tags: c#, contravariance

I'm trying to understand contravariance in practice. It seemed to be straightforward when I read the book, but now I seem to have stuck. 
I understand there's a lot of topics on contravariance and I've googled many of them, none helped me understand this particular problem 
Here's what Microsoft docs say https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

And here's my code:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace CSharpTests 
{
    class Program 
    {
        delegate void Action<T> (T obj);

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {

            Action<Device> b = DeviceAction;
            Action<Mouse> d = b; // Error cannot implicitly convert type CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Device> to CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Mouse>
            d(new Mouse());

            ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DeviceAction(Device target) {
            WriteLine(target.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    class Device { }
    class Mouse : Device { } 
}
```

What is the crucial difference? My code doesn't even compile. As you can see I've got a delegate accepting generic type which, as far as I understand, allows contravariance. But on practice, I got a compile time error.
I also try to do it with the "out" parameter and got the same error

```
using static System.Console;

namespace CSharpTests {

    class Program {

        delegate void Action<T> (out T obj);

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Action<Device> b = DeviceAction;
            Action<Mouse> d = b; // Error cannot implicitly convert type CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Device> to CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Mouse>
            Mouse m;
            d(out m);

            ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DeviceAction(out Device target) {
            target = new Device();
            WriteLine(target.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    class Device { }
    class Mouse : Device { } 
}
```

Comment: If you follow the links to e.g. `Action` from that document, you'll see that *you have to decorate the type parameters with `in` or `out` to actually declare their variance*

Comment: I tried to do it, and I wrote about that. It gave me just the same error

Comment: I think you have declared the type Action with the line `delegate void Action<T> (T obj);` but it is not marked as being contravarient - to do that you would write `delegate void Action<in T> (T obj);`

Comment: `out` in `<out T>(...)` has a different meaning to `<T>(out T value)`.

Comment: Change the signature to `delegate void Action<in T>`.  `in` indicates contravariance; `out` indicates covariance.  You can usually tell which one to use because `in` is for _inputs_ (e.g., parameters) and `out` is for _outputs_ (e.g., return values).

Comment: @Mike ahh, exactly! You've just saved my nerves :D Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot accept comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature to `delegate void Action<in T>(T arg)`.

Declaring a type parameter as  `in` indicates contravariance; `out` indicates covariance.

You can usually tell which one to use because `in` is for *inputs* (e.g., parameters) and `out` is for *outputs* (e.g., return values).

Answer (score 3):

Here you are declaring an invariant `T` with an `out` *parameter*:

```
delegate void Action<T> (out T obj);
```

Moving `out` to `Action<out T>` would give you a *covariant `T`* instead. What you wanted to do is this (a contravariant `T` with a parameter):

```
delegate void Action<in T> (T obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well your creating a  target = new Device();
this is not the same as what you put in...

Try like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class Method_Tetsts
{
    class Device { }
    class Mouse : Device { }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ActionTest()
    {

        void DeviceAction<T>( T target)
        {  
            Assert.AreEqual(target.GetType().Name, "Mouse");
        }

        Action<Device> b = DeviceAction;
        Action<Mouse> d = b; // Error cannot implicitly convert type CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Device> to CSharpTests.Program.Action<CSharpTests.Mouse>
        d(new Mouse());
    }
}
```